# How to avoid infinite loop when conforming to a protocol with the same variable name in Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

Given the following protocol in FooModule:

```
protocol Id {
    var id: String { get }
}

protocol Foo {
    var id: Id { get }
}
```

...and some type from ThirdPartyModule that does not conform to it, but that already has a property `id`:

```
struct 3rdPartyId {
   var id: String
}

struct 3rdPartyElement {
    var id: 3rdPartyId
}
```

Now I want to make:

```
extension 3rdPartyId: MyModule.Id {
    var id: String { return self.id }
}

extension 3rdPartyElement: MyModule.Element {
    var id: MyModule.Id { return self.id }
}
```

However this results in an infinite loop.

How can I extend 3rdPartyElement to conform to MyModule.Element protocol without having an infinite loop...?

I also tried just declaring it like this:

```
extension 3rdPartyElement: MyModule.Element {}
```

... because there is already a property `id` of a type that should satisfy the protocol. However this does not work either, I get a compiler error telling me to add the property getter that will, of course, make a loop.

Comment: I don't get a compiler error as you do when I try to use an 'empty' extension definition.  Though I didn't try putting my classes in completely separate libraries.  I'm trying in Swift 5; is it possible other versions of Swift behave differently?

Comment: Swift does not allow to declare two same name properties within one type, even if those properties have different types.

Comment: @Asperi See the answer I provided below.

Comment: @SeanSklly I think the answer I provided below should make this more clear. If `extension Bar.Id: Id {}` were to declare `var id: Id { return self.id }` then it would be an infinite loop. Moving the accessor into an extension on the protocol fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
public enum Bar {
    @frozen
    public struct Id {
        private var _id: String = ""
        public var id: String {
            get { _id }
            set { _id = newValue }
        }
        public init(id: String) {
            _id = id
        }
    }

    @frozen
    public struct Bar {
        public var id: Id
    }
}

// MARK: - Protocols

protocol Id {
    var id: String { get }
}

protocol Foo {
    var id: Id { get }
}

// MARK: - Conformance

// (1) Declare that the type conforms to the protocol 
//     (won't compile without the second extension below)
extension Bar.Id: Id {}

// (2) Extend the protocol enough to ensure the compiler
//     knows how the protocol conformance declared in (1)
//     is supposed to actually work.  
extension Id where Self == Bar.Id {
    var id: String { self.id }
    init(id: String) {
        self.init(id: id)
    }
}

// (1) Declare that the type conforms to the protocol 
//     (won't compile without the second extension below)
extension Bar.Bar: Foo {}

// (2) Extend the protocol enough to ensure the compiler
//     knows how the protocol conformance declared in (1)
//     is supposed to actually work.  
extension Foo where Self == Bar.Bar {
    var id: Id { self.id }
}
```

The key is that you need *two* extensions: one that declares that the type conforms to the protocol, and one that extends the protocol with a `where` clause and provides the necessary glue to satisfy the compiler that the protocol's requirements are satisfied by the type in question.

This only works because the function bodies / property accessors inside protocol extensions have a special ability that is only true of protocol extensions (but not of extensions on structs/classes).

This special ability of protocol extensions is that the implementation in the extension can access the struct's/class's original implementation *of the same variable or function* that's declared inside any type that conforms to the protocol that's being extended and that meets the requirements of the `where` clause.

Due to this special ability of protocol extensions, the following is not an infinite loop:

```
extension Foo where Self == Bar.Bar {
    var id: Id { self.id }
}
```